# Telerik Reports, Parameter Area not bind parameters.(parameters works, But not shown in parameter area)

Tags: html, telerik, telerik-reporting

Probably, there is a very simple solution but i can't find.
i want to add report parameter for dynamic filtering by end user.
It's seen in preview, But i can't find it in browser view.
is there any one have an idea?

**Here is preview**
[image: Preview]

**Here is browser view**
[image: Browser View]

**My index view**

```
<div id="reportViewer1" class="k-widget">
        loading...
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $reportViewer = $("#reportViewer1")
            .telerik_ReportViewer({
                serviceUrl: "/api/reports/",
                templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html div.trv-report-viewer',
                reportSource: { report: "MyClassLib.Group, MyClassLib" },
                viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewMode.Interactive,
                scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,
                scale: 1.0
            });

    </script>
```

**Parameter settings**

[image: Parameter Settings]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Telerik Report viewer? I do not even see the icon showing that there are parameters available! Which version are you using?

Comment: I m New and i don't know that icon showing that there are parameters available sory but versiyon is Q3  and in HTML5

Comment: Telerik Reporting Q3 2013 (7.1.13.1016) 
Parameters must shown in right side but it says not found

Answer (score 0):

From the information you may supply here would be difficult to catch where the problem occurred.
Make sure you are using a Telerik reportViewer. From your comments I understand that you do not know exactly what to look for so I suggest you to follow step by step this Telerik [video](http://tv.telerik.com/watch/reporting/video/telerik-trainer-reporting-parameters).

Let us know if you do not come right.

Comment: i think i know now. Its telerik reportViewer, i'm sure of that. I watch it before asked this question.Everything is same except database, and also he is using windows form app, i used Kendo UI Mvc App. But thanks for helping replies